# Giant "A" appears occasionally since latest Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10-v1703

Since getting the new Creators Edition of Windows 10 in the middle of the week, occasionally when starting new applications (I think) a huge 96 point or so sans-serif `A` appears in the middle of the screen, then disappears after a second or so. It sort of feels like it might be connected to some kind of multi-monitor check, but I have just a single HDMI one using a boring old Intel motherboard graphics card. There are no obvious problems, it's just kind of annoying.

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot?

Comment: Do you get the same toggling upper case and lower case?

Comment: My keyboard software does something similar when I turn on Caps Lock or Num Lock.

Comment: @FrankThomas: thanks for the hint; I started looking at keyboard issues after that, so see my self-answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. Right click the Japanese ime tray icon (right click the A or あ icon) and enter the property. You will see a check box saying "Display input mode at center of screen" is checked. Uncheck it and you will not see it anymore.

[image]

Comment: This answer is great but it's also written in a way that makes it not clear

Comment: I don't know how to upload a picture. Click the enter image description here. You will see the process.

Comment: Thanks - I thought I looked through all the menus, but that works perfectly.